# How to delete line with specific line numbers and save deleted and the rest?

Tags: sed, grep

test.txt contains:

```
this is a line
another line
one more line
```

For example, this can remove 1-2 lines, and save the rest into the rest.txt

```
sed -e '1,2d' test.txt > rest.txt
```

But the original file remains intact. Then how to get the remaining lines from the file? In this example, I want to remove the first 2 lines, save them into a file 'deleted.txt', and save the 3rd line into 'rest.txt'.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: this would work `awk 'NR<=2{print $0 > "deleted.txt"}NR>2{print $0 > "rest.txt"}' test.txt`

Comment: @P..... deleted.txt is right, but the rest.txt contains 3 '$0'

Comment: edited now, it was a typo. Try again with updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk 'NR<=2{print $0 > "deleted.txt"}NR>2{print $0 > "rest.txt"}' test.txt
```

For lines(here `NR`) `<= 2` redirect the output to deleted.
For lines(here `NR`) `> 2` redirect the output to rest.txt.

Comment: One more challenging question, to randomly delete 100 lines, probably that is not possible through an awk command. Right?

Comment: Can't say not possible. I do not know it.

Comment: what about I want to delete any lines between m to n? i.e. 500-5000. This would be more general.

Comment: yes, you can do that. `awk 'NR>=m && NR<=n{print $0 > "deleted.txt"}'`. you can make `m` and `n` variables by `awk -v m=500 -v n=5000 ' NR>=m && NR<=n{print $0 > "deleted.txt"}'`

Comment: try `awk 'NR>=500 && NR <=5000{print $0 > "deleted.txt"}NR<500{print $0 > "rest.txt"} R>5000{print $0 > "rest.txt"}' test.txt`

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
seq 1 5 | sed -e '1,2w deleted.txt' -e '1,2d' > rest.txt
```

> `w filename`: Write the current pattern space to filename.

Comment: What should rest.txt contain?

Comment: 5 is the total line number in the file?. Plus, in the command, it doesn't have the test.txt file name but it still works. why is that?

Comment: `seq 1 5` sends numbers from 1 to 5 to sed's [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). I assume that's what you're looking for: `sed -e '1,2w deleted.txt' -e '1,2d' test.txt > rest.txt`

Comment: Perhaps `sed -e '1,2{w deletedLines' -e 'd}' file > minusDeletedLines`?